# Ajax contact form is not sending an email

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, email

I'm using ajax contact form:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function () {
    // Comment or uncomment the result you want.
    // Currently, shake on error is enabled.
    // When a field is left blank, jQuery will shake the form

    /* Begin config */

    //  var shake = "Yes";
    var shake = "No";

    /* End config */

    $('#message').hide();

    // Add validation parts
    $('#contact input[type=text], #contact input[type=number], #contact input[type=email], #contact input[type=url], #contact input[type=tel], #contact select, #contact textarea').each(function () {
        $(this).after('<mark class="validate"></mark>');
    });

    // Validate as you type
    $('#email').focusout(function () {
        if (!$(this).val() || !isEmail($(this).val())) $(this).addClass('error').parent().find('mark').removeClass('valid').addClass('error');
        else $(this).removeClass('error').parent().find('mark').removeClass('error').addClass('valid');
    });

    $('#submits').click(function () {
        $("#message").slideUp(200, function () {
            $('#message').hide();

            // Kick in Validation
            $('#email').triggerHandler("focusout");

            if ($('#contact mark.error').size() > 0) {
                if (shake == "Yes") {
                    $('#contact').effect('shake', {
                        times: 2
                    }, 75, function () {
                        $('#contact input.error:first, #contact textarea.error:first').focus();
                    });
                } else $('#contact input.error:first, #contact textarea.error:first').focus();

                return false;
            }

        });
    });

    $('#contactform').submit(function () {

        if ($('#contact mark.error').size() > 0) {
            if (shake == "Yes") {
                $('#contact').effect('shake', {
                    times: 2
                }, 75);
            }
            return false;
        }

        var action = $(this).attr('action');

        $('#submits')
            .after('<img src="/system/cms/themes/default/views/partials/assets/ajax-loader.gif" class="loader" />')
            .attr('disabled', 'disabled');

        $.post(action, {
            name: $('#name').val(),
            email: $('#email').val(),
            phone: $('#phone').val(),
            website: $('#website').val(),
            kvk: $('#kvk').val(),
            sending: $('#sending').val(),
            webwinkel: $('#webwinkel').val(),
            pakketten: $('#pakketten').val(),
        },

        function (data) {
            $('#message').html(data);
            $('#message').slideDown();
            $('#contactform img.loader').fadeOut('slow', function () {
                $(this).remove()
            });
            $('#contactform #submits').attr('disabled', '');
            if (data.match('success') != null) $('#contactform').slideUp('slow');

        });

        return false;

    });

    function isEmail(emailAddress) {

        var pattern = new RegExp(/^(("[\w-\s]+")|([\w-]+(?:\.[\w-]+)*)|("[\w-\s]+")([\w-]+(?:\.[\w-]+)*))(@((?:[\w-]+\.)*\w[\w-]{0,66})\.([a-z]{2,6}(?:\.[a-z]{2})?)$)|(@\[?((25[0-5]\.|2[0-4][0-9]\.|1[0-9]{2}\.|[0-9]{1,2}\.))((25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|1[0-9]{2}|[0-9]{1,2})\.){2}(25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|1[0-9]{2}|[0-9]{1,2})\]?$)/i);

        return pattern.test(emailAddress);
    }

    function isNumeric(input) {
        return (input - 0) == input && input.length > 0;
    }
});
```

In some way it is not sending the email if i exclude this script the email script does work?

Ive tried everything but i can't get it to work , i think its strange because im using this script on more places and there its working :(...

anyone idea's ?

*** Update Mail script ***

```
<?php if (!isset($_SESSION)) session_start();

if(!$_POST) exit();

    if (!defined("PHP_EOL")) define("PHP_EOL", "\r\n");

    $name       = $_POST['name'];
    $email      = $_POST['email'];
    $phone      = $_POST['phone'];
    $website    = $_POST['website'];
    $kvk        = $_POST['kvk'];
    $sending    = $_POST['sending'];
    $webwinkel  = $_POST['webwinkel'];
    $pakketten  = $_POST['pakketten'];
    $error      = '';

    if (isset($_POST['verify'])) :
        $posted_verify   = $_POST['verify'];
        $posted_verify   = md5($posted_verify);
    else :
        $posted_verify = '';
    endif;

    // Important Variables
    $session_verify = $_SESSION['verify'];

    if (empty($session_verify)) $session_verify = $_COOKIE['verify'];



    if($error == '') {

    if(get_magic_quotes_gpc()) {
            $comments = stripslashes($comments);
        }

     // Configuration option.

     $address = "email@email.com";


     // Configuration option.
     // i.e. The standard subject will appear as, "You've been contacted by John Doe."

     // Example, $e_subject = '$name . ' has contacted you via Your Website.';

     $e_subject = 'Nieuwe Aanmelding';


     // Configuration option.
     // You can change this if you feel that you need to.
     // Developers, you may wish to add more fields to the form, in which case you must be sure to add them here.

     $e_body  = "Er is een nieuwe aanmelding binnen gekomen:\n\n" . PHP_EOL . PHP_EOL;
     $e_name  = "Name: $name \n\n";
     $e_email = "Email: $email \n\n";
     $e_phone = "Tel: $phone \n\n";
     $e_kvk   = "KVK: $kvk \n\n";
     $e_website   = "Website: $website \n\n";
     $e_sending = "Verzending nu: $sending \n\n";
     $e_winkel= "Webwinkel: $webwinkel \n\n";
     $e_pakketten= "Paketten per maand: $pakketten \n \n";

     $msg = wordwrap($e_body . $e_name . $e_email . $e_website  . $e_phone . $e_kvk . $e_sending . $e_winkel . $e_pakketten,70);

     $headers = "From: $email" . PHP_EOL;
     $headers .= "Reply-To: $email" . PHP_EOL;
     $headers .= "MIME-Version: 1.0" . PHP_EOL;
     $headers .= "Content-type: text/plain; charset=utf-8" . PHP_EOL;
     $headers .= "Content-Transfer-Encoding: quoted-printable" . PHP_EOL;

     if(mail($address, $e_subject, $msg, $headers)) {


     // Email has sent successfully, echo a success page.

     echo "<div class='span12'>";
     echo "<div class='span4'></div>";
     echo "<div class='span6'>";
     echo "<div id='success_page'>";
     echo "<h1 style='color:white'>Uw aanmelding is verzonden.</h1>";
     echo "<p style='color:white'>Bedankt <strong>$name</strong>, U wordt zo spoedig mogelijk geholpen.</p>";
     echo "</div>";
     echo "</div>";

     } else {

     echo 'ERROR!';

     }

}
 ?>
```

**Resolved**

Guys,

Thanks for the quick response.

This is the new jquery ive just downloaded and its working now.

```
$('#contactform').submit(function(){

    if ($('#contact mark.error').size()>0) {
        if(shake == "Yes") {
        $('#contact').effect('shake', { times:2 }, 75);
        }
        return false;
    }

    var action = $(this).attr('action');

    $('#submit')
        .after('<img src="assets/img/ajax-loader.gif" class="loader" />')
        .attr('disabled','disabled');

    $.post(action, $('#contactform').serialize(),
        function(data){
            $('#message').html( data );
            $('#message').slideDown();
            $('#contactform img.loader').fadeOut('slow',function(){$(this).remove()});
            $('#contactform #submit').removeAttr('disabled');
            if(data.match('success') != null) $('#contactform').slideUp('slow');

        }
    );

    return false;

});
```

Comment: JavaScript has a concept of boolean variables, there's no reason to be setting a variable storing a true or false value to "Yes" or "No".

Comment: Where is the server side code? Javascript does not send any mails, if the script works on "other" sites, there might me a specific problem with your current server config or server side code. It cannot be analysed without the server side code, which actually sends the email.

Comment: JavaScript doesn't send emails.  You need to narrow down the problem with some basic debugging.  How does this script tell another system to send an email?  Is the other system receiving the data it needs?  (You can, for example, monitor your HTTP POST values in a browser debugging tool such as FireBug or Chrome developer tools.)  Where specifically does the code fail?  What are the runtime values when that happens?  Currently your question isn't answerable.  "I copied and pasted some code and something else isn't happening" isn't a question.

Answer (score 0):

There's so much wrong on so many levels, please first take a look at www.phptherightway.com.

After that, try and figure out if the form is being sent to the server (via the POST request method). If it's not, I'm guessing the form is returning false on the submit event, and that'll be the reason it's not working most likely.